# Given a list of edges, how many connected components can be found?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Given a list of edges such that the undirected graph generated cannot have multiple edges but can have loops. How many connected components can be found?

This is best demonstrated with an example.
Given this list of edges:

```
A -- A
A -- B
B -- C
B -- D
B -- F
G -- H
H -- I
I -- G
```

There are two connected components that can be found:

[image]

Is there a way to determine how many connected components can be found without actually constructing the graph?

Comment: What kinds of graphs are you thinking of? Simple graphs? Also, are you only allowed to consider graphs with these eight exact vertices?

Comment: @TeddantheTerran


I'm not familiar with graph theory terminology yet, so forgive me if I don't answer well.


I'm considering any number of vertices. Just given list of edges where the number of edges is any positive number.


These are directed graphs, so I don't think they are considered simple, no.
I have an image of my example graph in my question if that helps.

Comment: No problem! But if you allow *any* set of vertices that includes A, B, C, D, F, G, I, and H, then there are infinitely many graphs that satisfy your conditions, so there must be some kind of restriction.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Could I just add vertex X to your picture without any edges?  Would that count?  Could I add some extra edges?  Or do you want a digraph with exactly these vertices and exactly these edges?

Comment: @saulspatz

Yes, if you were to add a vertex X without any connections, or even something like $X \to Y$, then there would be 3 graphs in that case.

Maybe I'm misinterpreting what the term graph means. Really I'm just interested in how many different sets of connected vertices are there.

Comment: @TeddantheTerran

I'm not sure I understand. If you were given the list of edges like in my example above. There would only be 2 graphs possible, right?

Comment: You are misinterpreting the terminology.  There is only one graph in your picture.  You are talking about *components.*  In an undirected graph, a component is a maximal subgraph such that there is a path of edges between any two vertices in the component.  In a digraph, it is usual to consider *strongly-connected* components, that is, maximal subgraphs with a directed path from any vertex to any other.  The component on the left is not strongly-connected, because there is no directed path from $B$ to $A$.  If we we to consider strongly-connected components, ...

Comment: @PeterTran If can use as many vertices as I want to, I can construct a graph satisfying your conditions that has $n+8$ vertices, for *any* $n$: Just add $n$ vertices to any of the graphs you gave as examples and connect each of them to A

Comment: ... the vertices $A$ and $F$ would each be a strongly connected component on its own.  Edges $AB$ and $BF$ would not belong to any strongly-connected component.  There are four strongly connected components.  Furthermore, a graph is completely determined by its vertices and edges.  As @TeddantheTerran has indicated, I don't think you really men to allow extra edges and vertices to be added, or the question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: If you can edit your question to explain exactly what you are looking for, I'm sure I can solve your problem.

Comment: Ahh you're exactly right, I'm looking for the number of connected components in a graph.

In this case then, I don't think I'm looking for strongly connected components. I think I could represent my graph as an undirected graph where I want to just find the number of connected components. The fact that my example is directed doesn't help address my underlying question.

And yeah I don't mean to allow the ability to add extra edges and vertices. I've edited my question to clarify.

Comment: Now that I know the correct terminology, I'm also able to search the internet for what I'm looking for. I would still absolutely appreciate any advice though!

Comment: I've further specified the conditions for my question after I realized that the given edges will never produce multiple edges but can produce loops.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a depth first search approach to solving this:

```
a) Pick a random node and mark as visited
b) Find all nodes adjacent and repeat algorithm on each
c) If no adjacent nodes are found, exit

d) Increment component counter by 1
e) Repeat algorithm if not all nodes in the list have been visited
```

This isn't a mathematical solution as I had hoped for, but it works.